# Agregar más roles al bot de Discord

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de agregar múltiples roles en `on_message` de Discord en el código python del bot, pero no consigo hacerlo.

Aquí dejo mi código:

```
import discord
import re
 
client = discord.Client()

@commands.has_any_role("rol1", "rol2")
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  
        urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+',message.content.lower())
        if urls and message.channel.id in [898093316804059157]:
            await message.channel.send(f" Hey, {message.author.mention} No puedes mandar links")
            await message.delete()
            




client.run("")
```

Mensaje de error:

[image: Captura de pantalla del error]

Comment: ¿Por qué no consigues hacerlo? ¿Te da error, resultado incorrecto, te falta algo?

Comment: me da error al añadir @commands.has_any_role("rol1", "rol2")

Comment: Que error te da? Que es commands? Podrías agregar en la pregunta un código que de ese mismo error por favor? No puedo ayudarte si no das un código que de ese mismo error.

Comment: ya deje el codigo

Comment: ¿Podrías probar a importar `commands` con `from discord.ext import commands` al comienzo de tu script? Ten en cuenta que [`commands` está dentro de `discord.ext`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html) (es `discord.ext.commands.has_any_role()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que te faltó importar el modulo commands de discord.ext, como te dijo OscarGarcia. Si esto fuera lo unico que hay que arreglar para que funcionase, no habría hecho esta respuesta.

Luego de hacer lo que dijo OscarGarcia, la función on_message se ejecutará incluso si el usuario no tiene el rol.

No hay nada de malo en su respuesta. De hecho, soluciona el error que te aparece. Pero yo quería ir más allá y ayudarte también con futuros errores que te surgirían.

Ya intenté de todo para poder usar el decorador `has_any_rol` junto al decorador `bot.event` y la funcion on_message y no dió resultado.

#### Solución

Crea tu propia función para verificar si el autor del mensaje tiene el rol.
Para esto no necesitamos importar discord.ext.commands

```
import discord
import re
 
client = discord.Client()

def has_roles(member, *roles):
    # creo un conjunto con los nombres de los roles que tiene el miembro
    roles_del_miembro = {role.name for role in member.roles}
    
    # Uso el operador de union para saber que roles están en el conjunto de roles buscados y los roles del miembro.
    # roles es una tupla, pero necesitamos un conjunto, así que lo convertimos en conjunto.
    # Esta operación nos devolverá un conjunto con los roles que están en ambos conjuntos.
    # Pero como no nos interesa saber que roles están en ambos, solo si HAY roles en ambos, lo convertimos en booleano.
    # Si esta operación devuelve un set vacío, la función bool devolverá False, de lo contrario, True
    return bool(roles_del_miembro & set(roles))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):    
    if(has_roles(message.author, "rol1", "rol2")):
        # Supongo que lo que quieres saber aquí es si hay al menos un link en el mensaje.
        # Para eso no es necesario obtener una lista de todos los links del mensaje (esto es lo que hace tu findall).
        # Nos alcanza buscar hasta que ocurra la primera coincidencia. Por eso usaremos la función search en su lugar.
        urls = re.search('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+',message.content.lower())
        # Guarda! Por motivo de pruebas, cambié el id del canal en esta linea. Si quieres que funcione, coloca de nuevo el id del canal donde harás este filtro.
        if urls and message.channel.id in [874812975280709673]:
            await message.channel.send(f" Hey, {message.author.mention} No puedes mandar links")
            await message.delete()
            
client.run("token del bot de prueba")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono , pero ahora el problema que el rol que quiero que manden el link lo auto borra

Comment: De casualidad puedes ingresar al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)? Me pasarias el código que da ese error por alli? Recuerda mencionarme con @DanteS. Estoy algo ocupado, así que no te aseguro una respuesta inmediata.

Comment: @Juan No te critico mal por hacerlo pero, por que saliste de nuestro chat? Si es por que no quieres que te enseñe antes de ayudarte, lo entiendo. Pero preferiria darte una pequeña recomendacion antes de que dejemos de hablar.

Comment: Sorry, se me fue el internet  tengo mala conexion

Comment: No pasa nada c: Bueno, te espero! Ojalà mi forma de ayudar te sirva!

Comment: @Juan te sigo ayudando?

Comment: Gracias @DanteS. por haber seguido con la ayuda. Si hubiera contestado al comentario que le dejé o a la respuesta que redacté podría haberle ayudado más. Ahora te ha dejado colgado a ti.

Comment: @OscarGarcia De nada? Igual si me deja colgado, no es mi problema, el que quiere ayuda es el. Yo no gano dinero al ayudarlo. Mi comentario fue mas por el que por mi.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer uso del decorador `@commands` antes deberás importar `commands` de `discord.ext`:

```
from discord.ext import commands
```